# Can docker solve a problem of mismatched C shared libraries?

Tags: linux, docker, haskell, haskell-stack, libc

I am trying to run some haskell code on an ubuntu (18.04) host, which was compiled on my laptop.

```
host: 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

laptop: 4.14.74-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 5 14:16:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The error I get is

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found
```

After doing some research I learned that this is because my laptop has version 2.28 of glibc installed, but the host only has libc6 2.27.

I did some googling and figured that maybe docker could solve this problem. However, I just created a docker image with the following Dockerfile and it didn't work (same GLIBC_2.28 error)

```
FROM fpco/stack-build:lts-12.9 as builder

RUN mkdir /opt/build
COPY . /opt/build
RUN cd /opt/build && stack build 

FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN mkdir -p /opt/myapp
WORKDIR /opt/myapp
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /opt/build/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-12.9/8.4.3/bin .
CMD ["/opt/myapp/myapp-exe"]
```

I'm not sure what to do now. I have a few questions:

- Why am I getting this problem in the first place? I thought I read somewhere that glibc is backwards compatible? (Is glibc the same thing as libc6..?)
- Is there a way to use docker to get around this problem? Could i run my build process inside an ubuntu image? e.g. `FROM fcpo/stack-build:lts-12.9 and ubutu:18.04`, then later on creating another ubuntu image into which i copy my binary?
- Has anybody else run into this before ? If so did you find a solution (other than just changing operating system?)?

Comment: Adding another layer of complexity is unlikely to simplify your problem. Can you rebuild your program in the new environment or run it remotely?

Comment: I would rather do the compilation on my machine because the host is slow (not helped by stack taking a long time to compile all the dependencies), and I have limited bandwidth. But yes ideally I would have a machine which did have such an up to date version of glibc... I just wondered if anybody else had had this issue and solved it

Comment: It can solve this problem yes. Are you sure your docker image has glibc 2.28? But can you not just update glibc on the host?

Comment: Just clearing up confusion: glibc 2 = libc6. glibc being backwards compatible means that newer glibc supports programs built for older glibc. You need glibc to be forwards compatible to get a program built on later glibc to work with older glibc; it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why am I getting this problem in the first place? I thought I read somewhere that glibc is backwards compatible?

GLIBC *is* backwards compatible (programs built against old GLIBC continue to work on newer GLIBC), but the *inverse* is not true.

In your case, you built on a newer (GLIBC-2.28) system, and are trying to run on an older one (GLIBC-2.27). That is not guaranteed to work (although it might for sufficiently simple programs).

> Is there a way to use docker to get around this problem?

You need to *build* against the oldest version of GLIBC that you are planning to use.

You can achieve this in multiple ways:

- use a Linux to older Linux crosscompiler
- use a chroot build environment
- use a docker container with older GLIBC *at build time*.

Or you could *run* in a docker container that has the GLIBC-2.28 that your program needs.

Comment: thanks! i feel a bit dumb about the backwards compatibility now... I have realised that I can try doing `FROM ubuntu:18.04 $do build$, FROM ubuntu:18.04 $copy executables$`

Comment: hmm just looked and the image `fpco/stack-build:lts-12.9` uses ubuntu 16.04 (which has glibc < 2.28) which implies that the docker container must be using the shared C libraries from my laptop rather than the ubuntu image (otherwise it would have 'just worked')? nonetheless i will try it with ubuntu 18.04 later