# Using libc and libm from RHEL 6 to RHEL 7

Tags: compilation, glibc

My application links to libraries which are built on RHEL 6. When I compile this application on RHEL 7 linker throws errors for glibc version.
Following is one of the error :

*undefined reference to symbol '__tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.12'
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*

For fixing I copied libc and libm from RHEL 6 to RHEL 7 and linked to these along with libc and libm from RHEL 7. Will it cause issue at runtime if I copy libc and libm from RHEL 6 to RHEL 7?
Any other way to get away with such issues?

Thanks,
Mangesh Sawant.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it cause issue at runtime if I copy libc and libm from RHEL 6 to RHEL 7?

Copying `libc.so.6` and `libm.so.6` from RHEL6 to e.g.  `~/rhel6/libs` or `/tmp` will not cause any issues (you've already done it).

But *overwriting* the RHEL7's `/lib64/libc.so.6` with RHEL6's copy is likely to make *every* program on the RHEL7 system to crash, and render that system unbootable. Make sure you have backups and a rescue disk, and know how to use it if you decide to try this.

> Any other way to get away with such issues?

Correct way to deal with this is to build with a toolchain that *targets* desired GLIBC.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52827558/50617).

Answer (score 0):

While Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 came with glibc 2.12, it does not have a `__tls_get_addr@GLIBC_2.12` versioned symbol, only `__tls_get_addr@GLIBC_2.3`. That symbol is also present in later glibc versions.

I don't think the problem you are facing can be solved by downgrading glibc. As [Employed Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50617/employed-russian) said, overwriting the system glibc will make the system unbootable anyway.