# Dockerized Jenkins not able to find docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to establish a Jenkins Pipeline, that's able to build docker images. But I ran into the problem `docker: not found` after executing the pipeline. The `Jenkinsfile` has the following content:

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker --version '
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a simple script to get things started. But it seems that the dockerized Jenkins installation can't find a suitable docker installation to use.
The required plugins (`Docker` and `Docker pipeline`) are installed and a global docker installation configuration is present. But the error keeps going.

Jenkins setup is done by using this `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.1'

networks:
  docker:

volumes:
  jenkins-data:
  jenkins-docker-certs:

services:

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    restart: always
    networks:
      - docker
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
      - 50000:50000
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro
      - $HOME:/home
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376
      - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client
      - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

  dind:
    image: docker:dind
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    networks:
      docker:
        aliases:
          - docker
    ports:
      - 2376:2376
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client
      - $HOME:/home
    environment:
      - DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs
```

After reading some more posts about that issue and following the official Jenkins doc, I thought that for this purpose `docker:dind` is used. Maybe I miss some important configurations here? When launching the `docker:dind` container, the log states the following warning message: `could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found`, but the group exists and I'm able to run docker commands without specifying `sudo`. (Followed the official docker post-installation steps)

Another problematic point right now is, that Jenkins can't persist configuration data in general or pipeline related stuff. After restarting the machine I have to go through the wizard every single time and I don't know why.

Did someone suffer similar problems?

Many thanks in advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your docker-compose file is correct, you just need to add a volume in the jenkins container :

```
- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```

You have also a lot of configuration not required, you can check this [link](https://www.tiuweehan.com/blog/2020-09-10-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/) to see others possible configurations. You use actually the Solution 3 and you can switch to this docker-compose file.

For volumes, they should be persisted since they are declared in the volume section. You can try to use [external volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference) if needed.

Comment: Indeed, many thanks for that great article, fixed the originated problem that docker can't be found. Suffering another problem now: `docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by docker)`. The host's `GLIBC` version is `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.33-0ubuntu5) 2.33` what's going on here?

Comment: where do you get this ?

Comment: Within my pipeline script. `+ docker inspect -f . node:14-alpine
docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by docker)` and a few lines below `+ docker pull node:14-alpine
docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by docker)`

Comment: I don't really know, but I'v found some explications about it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52827558/7953086 
it seems that you need to found aother version

Answer (score 0):

Fast forward one year and I've run into analogous problem, only with mismatched GLIBC versions, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093743/downgrading-docker-on-the-host-to-match-containers-older-glibc-doable-good-i).

I solved it by upgrading GLIBC version in the Jenkins container to 2.35 (as shipped with Ubuntu Jammy on the host). To achieve this I had to build my own Jenkins container based on `ubuntu:jammy` and JDK 17, using a template from the official Debian-based one (sourced from [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/17/debian/bullseye/hotspot/Dockerfile)). Now GLIBC versions agree, and docker-in-docker Jenkins builds can be made using docker installed on a host with Ubuntu Jammy:

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35

# vs.

$ docker run --rm -it mirekphd/jenkins-jdk17-on-ubuntu-2204:2.374 ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35
```

Feel free to use this container (best served with the `latest` tag), as I will have to maintain it for our own in-house use, setting its builds as one of... Jenkins pipelines (bootstrap problem notwithstanding). It will be a Docker-in-Docker Jenkins-in-Jenkins pipeline:)