# Downgrading Docker on the host to match container's older GLIBC: doable / good idea?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, debian, glibc

After migrating our build server's OS to the latest Ubuntu LTS (`ubuntu:jammy`) I quickly run into GLIBC incompatibility issue with the latest Debian (`debian:bullseye`) used in the latest official pre-built Jenkins containers (`jenkins/jenkins:jdk17`), a problem already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110198/jenkins-error-buildind-docker-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libc-so-6-version-glibc). This is expected, because that would require *forward* compatibility to work: container-installed dependencies (GLIBC 2.31) are older than the host-installed software (`docker` built under and expecting GLIBC 2.35).

Since there are no regularly maintained Jenkins Docker images using GLIBC version 2.35 compatible with the latest Ubuntu LTS (they would have to be using Debian Bookworm as a base or even Jammy itself) is it a) possible and b) a good idea (stability-, and security-wise) to downgrade docker on the host to match Debian container's older GLIBC version (2.31)? That would save me from reinstalling the entire host OS to the previous Ubuntu LTS and from maintaining custom Jenkins containers based on Debian Bookworm for its GLIBC 2.35 (possibly for a long time).

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary since each container has its own isolated library stack: the host libc plays no relation to the type, version, or presence of libc in any given container.  There's potential problems if the host's kernel is much older than a given container's libc expects but that's not your situation.

Comment: Please note that this (rather popular) method of docker injection to the (Jenkins) container takes only docker binary from the host. This can result in an untested combination of the newer app from the host (`/usr/bin/docker`) and its older dependencies (`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`) from the container. Among other benefits it allows me to use off-the-shelf Jenkins containers and run them under unpriviledged user IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the first part of the question: **not doable**.

First, after the downgrade, docker would run into the same C API compatibility issues on the host itself (the docker would be only usable inside Jenkins containers). Second, there are no installation candidates for such a deep downgrade. In other words, supported docker versions gap between the two systems (host vs. container) is too wide (respectively 20.10.13 vs. 20.10.5).

---

*More info*

```
# host:
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt-cache madison docker-ce
[..]
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.19~3-0~ubuntu-jammy | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-jammy | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.17~3-0~ubuntu-jammy | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-jammy | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.15~3-0~ubuntu-jammy | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.14~3-0~ubuntu-jammy | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.13~3-0~ubuntu-jammy | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages

# container:
$ docker exec -it jenkins_jenkins bash -c "apt-cache madison docker.io"
 docker.io | 20.10.5+dfsg1-1+deb11u2 | http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by doing the exact opposite:

**upgrading** the *container* system to make its `libc` version match the newer one from the host, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74116770/9962007).